# Keeping a global count without using a field

Tags: java, variables, global-variables, private

I am writing a class for a project and what it does is play a game.
I need to keep track of every time I win the game and the total number of games played 
during one run.
I could easily use two private fields such as

private int gamesWon; and private int totalGames;

but assigning two private fields for such trivial things seems unnecessary.

I don't know how I would go about doing this. I was thinking of putting them in a private method but how would I keep the counts from not resetting every time?
Also, I would be calling said method every time I win the game, or a game is finished.

Thank you!

Comment: I would suggest that two private fields would be ideal for this. I don't really understand why you are concerned about using them?

Comment: fields are for such trivial things ... If you have 2 different Player Classes, use a field to count won games. If you have a Game(or some kind of Main-class) use a field to count the total games ...

Comment: If one of our answers helped you, accept it as solution to your question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the fields. You need to store the information somewhere. That's the simpliest solution at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid of fields! They are especially the "tool" you want to use here. It's just a bit of necessary information bound to a class.

If you feel you're mixing statistical information into your other-purpose class, design along the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and create a *Statistic* class which holds your counters. It encapsulates them, provides methods to increment and to read them.